# Remove Brackets from all the filenames in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a string that remove the brackets from the filename.

`$ find . -name "*.mkv" -exec rename 's/[\)\(]//g' {} \;`

I have managed to make a statement that removes all the `()` in the filename of a directory, but whenever I run into a directory like for example `amazing.(2018)` It shows an error that:

> No directory can be found.

Please provide any alternative I need this to work, and I want it to be recursive.

Comment: I want it to go recursively into sub-folders and by removing the `-name` restriction it is not working.

Comment: You need to add `-depth` so that subdirectories are renamed before parent directories. For example if you have `./foo(bar)/baz(qux)`, without -depth, `./foo(bar)` will be renamed, then find tries to rename `./foo(bar)/baz(qux)` but that path no longer exists.

Comment: By adding `-depth` the error is still there. Is there another way to implement the solution through sed or tr ?

Comment: @FarhanSajid : Can't be. Show us a transscript of your modified command and the error.

Comment: @FarhanSajid : Just out of curiosity: Which `rename` tool are you using? The one I have on my system, would not permit the syntax which you are employing.

Comment: @FarhanSajid : Also, in order to better see what is going on, you could add some tracing to your command, using the `-x` option of bash: Replace the -exec part by `-exec bash -x "rename 's/[\)\(]//g' {}" \;`

Answer (score 0):

Better call `sed`:

`find . -type f -iname "*.mkv" | \
while IFS= read -r line; \
do mv "$line" "$(printf %s "$line" | sed -re 's/(\[|\])//g')"; done;`

input:
`'1[a].mkv'  '2[a].mkv'  '3[a].mkv'`

output:
`1a.mkv  2a.mkv  3a.mkv`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you run "find" with the "-depth" parameter,
therefore leafs are renamed first,
i.e., a directory name is changed
only *after* all files and directories inside it are renamed.

Otherwise, if you first change the name of a directory,
files and directories inside it are no longer accessible
(they are not in the list that "find" built at the beginning).